# Is TNA the originator of the six-sided ring?

Tags: pro-wrestling

Is TNA the originator of the six-sided ring?

Comment: With the update, this is a yes or no question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. A six-side ring was used in Japan, by the Tōryūmon project in 2000. That group went defunct during 2004, (perhaps not coincidentally) the year that TNA first used the six-side ring.